# WPF C# accessing a checkbox in a custom Tabitem control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

How do I get event notifications from a tabitem custom control that needs to be created dynamically?

I have buttons on mainWindow.xaml. I also have a tab control on this window. I am generating tab items dynamically based on the number of network interface cards that are on the machine via a custom control.
I read in the data from each network card into a separate tab item and fill the appropriate text boxes with MAC, IP, DNS, etc. In addition to the text boxes I have two check boxes useDHCP and automaticDNS. If a ValidationRule fails on the tab item, I would like to disable one of the buttons on the main window; specifically, the save button.
I believe that I have the validation logic functioning well enough to try and disable the save button if there was some bad data entered by the user. My trouble is gaining access to the events in the custom control so that I can react to the error and disable the Save Button from the main window.

When I add the custom control to the main window XAML as in:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabSettings" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
    Margin="10,10,10,10" 
    Background="#FF1B1B1B" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectionChanged="tabSettings_SelectionChanged" />
```

I don’t know how to access the events that will allow me to set the property to disable Save button. I do get all of the tabitems and all of the proper data.

Doing something like this, where I am declaring a custom control of type TabDataControl(which should be tab items):

```
<tabcntrl:TabDataControl x:Name="tabSettings" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
    Margin="10,10,10,10" 
    Background="#FF1B1B1B"
    UseDHCP_Click="NICTabs_UseDHCP_Click" 
    UseDNS_Click="NICTabs_UseDNS_Click" />
```

gets me at the events but since I don't know how to create multiple tabitems in this manner, I only get the first network card info to display.

Declaring the TabDataControl as a custom control to access the events from the main window allows me to see the events that I created as dependency properties. But I am not creating a tab for each network interface card.

To be concise here is the abbreviated class that creates some dependency properties.

```
namespace TabDataCustomControl {
    public partial class TabDataControl : Control { 
        private const string PART_USE_DHCP = "PART_useDHCP";
        private const string PART_TXT_CURRENTIP = "PART_txtBlkCurrentIP";
        private const string PART_TXT_CURRENTSN = "PART_txtBlkCurrentSN";
        private const string PART_USE_DNS = "PART_useDNS";

        static TabDataControl() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( TabDataControl ),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( TabDataControl ) ) );
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
            base.OnApplyTemplate(); 

            UseDHCP = GetTemplateChild( PART_USE_DHCP ) as CheckBox;
            UseDNS =  GetTemplateChild( PART_USE_DNS )  as CheckBox;
            TxtCurrentIP = GetTemplateChild( PART_TXT_CURRENTIP ) as TextBox;
            TxtCurrentSN = GetTemplateChild( PART_TXT_CURRENTSN ) as TextBox;
        }

        CheckBox useDHCP;
        protected CheckBox UseDHCP
        {
            get { return useDHCP; }
            set
            {
                if( useDHCP != null )
                {
                    useDHCP.MouseDown -= useDHCP_MouseDown;
                    useDHCP.Click -= useDHCP_Click;
                }
                useDHCP = value;

                if( useDHCP != null )
                {
                    useDHCP.MouseDown += useDHCP_MouseDown;
                    useDHCP.Click += useDHCP_Click;
                }  }  }

        void useDHCP_MouseDown( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {            RaiseUseDHCP_MouseDownEvent();        }

        protected static readonly RoutedEvent UseDHCP_MouseDownEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( "UseDHCP_MouseDown", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof( RoutedEventHandler ), typeof( TabDataControl ) );

        public event RoutedEventHandler UseDHCP_MouseDown {
            add { AddHandler( UseDHCP_MouseDownEvent, value ); }
            remove { RemoveHandler( UseDHCP_MouseDownEvent, value ); }
        }
        protected virtual void RaiseUseDHCP_MouseDownEvent() {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs( TabDataControl.UseDHCP_MouseDownEvent );
            RaiseEvent( args );
        }

        void useDHCP_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            RaiseUseDHCP_ClickEvent();
        }

        protected static readonly RoutedEvent UseDHCP_ClickEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( "UseDHCP_Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof( RoutedEventHandler ), typeof( TabDataControl ) );

        public event RoutedEventHandler UseDHCP_Click
        {
            add { AddHandler( UseDHCP_ClickEvent, value ); }
            remove { RemoveHandler( UseDHCP_ClickEvent, value ); }
        }
        protected virtual void RaiseUseDHCP_ClickEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs( TabDataControl.UseDHCP_ClickEvent );
            RaiseEvent( args );
        }
```

And here is the code from the mainWindow.xaml.cs. createTabs(); is called only from the mainWindow(); constructor.

```
private void createTabs()
{
    foreach ( var nicAdapter in NICAdapters )
    {
        string newTabeName = nicAdapter.AdapterName;

        //Create a new tab and set the data context.
        var NIC_Tab = new TabItem()
        {
            Header = newTabeName,
            Content = new TabDataControl(),
            DataContext = nicAdapter
        };
        tabSettings.Items.Add( NIC_Tab );
    }

    if ( tabSettings != null )
    {
        Style style = new Style( typeof( TabItem ), Application.Current.FindResource( "tabItemStyle" ) as Style );
        tabSettings.Resources.Add( typeof( TabItem ), style );
    }
    tabSettings.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel too many questions are being asked, and they're all rather unclear. As a result, I have a bunch of questions too... What is this checkbox we're having issues with? Where's the save button? Why does the second example have events but the first doesn't? Why does the first event have an `ItemsSource` for the `TabControl` but the second doesn't? What do the event handlers do and does it matter? Yikes! Where do we begin? Try to break the problem down for us a bit more.

Comment: I have to agree with you, and I apologize for not being more explicit. My trouble is the same as many other new programmers. I don’t understand the issue well enough yet to ask a well-formed question. I updated the post with as much detail as I dare without being overwhelming. The question is completely rewritten. I hope this is more clear? Thanks for any help and direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than suggest you continue on your journey down the path of click handlers and other nightmares, I'm going to push a different approach. (This is WPF we're talking about, of course, so that means you'll just have a bunch of different problems to solve... hah!)

You need separation of concerns. If you utilize some of the flexibility WPF makes available (even if they're a little dirty without some frameworks to help you out) your life will be quite a bit easier.

### View

Based on your question/code, I assume you are somewhat familiar with bindings and the `DataContext`. For this window, I have (crudely) instantiated a `MainViewModel` for it. The tab control has its `ItemsSource` set to the `Adapters` property of `MainViewModel`. Adding adapters to this collection will show the tab on the UI.

All of the properties for each adapter (in the `ContentTemplate` of `TabItem` style) are bound to the adapter object.

Note that we can enable and disable the IP Address/Subnet entry without any click handlers.

```
<Window x:Class="NicApp.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NicApp"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="500">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Adapters}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AdapterViewModel}">
                                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                    <CheckBox Content="Use DHCP" IsChecked="{Binding UseDhcp}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                                    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,15" IsEnabled="{Binding UseDhcp, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Content="IP Address" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Target="{Binding ElementName=IpAddressTextBox}" />
                                        <Label Content="Subnet Mask" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Target="{Binding ElementName=SubnetTextBox}" />
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding IPAddress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" x:Name="IpAddressTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Subnet, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" x:Name="SubnetTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                                    </Grid>

                                    <CheckBox Content="Use DNS" IsChecked="{Binding UseDns}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="OK" Width="100" Margin="0,10,10,0" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Width="100" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsCancel="True" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### ViewModels/Models

These are the objects that the XAML/view binds to.

These make use of `MVVM Light` (available in Nuget) because I wanted to make use of their `INotifyPropertyChanged` (tells WPF to update values on the UI as they change when you invoke `RaisePropertyChanged`) and `RelayCommand` (invokes an action after a button that is bound to a `RelayCommand` is clicked, as well as disables a button whose criteria for execution has not been met).

#### MainViewModel

The constructor needs to be updated to actually populate the collection based on network adapters you find. The accept and cancel commands also need to save the changes and cancel changes, respectively.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace NicApp
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // TODO actually load adapters
            Adapters = new ObservableCollection<AdapterViewModel>();
            Adapters.Add(new AdapterViewModel
            {
                Name = "Ethermet",
                IPAddress = "192.168.1.100",
                Subnet = "255.255.255.0",
                UseDhcp = true,
                UseDns = true
            });
            Adapters.Add(new AdapterViewModel
            {
                Name = "Wireless",
                IPAddress = "192.168.1.101",
                Subnet = "255.255.255.0",
                UseDhcp = false,
                UseDns = false
            });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<AdapterViewModel> _adapters;

        public ObservableCollection<AdapterViewModel> Adapters
        {
            get { return _adapters; }
            set { _adapters = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private RelayCommand _acceptCommand;
        private RelayCommand _cancelCommand;

        public RelayCommand AcceptCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _acceptCommand ?? (_acceptCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    // Accept action
                }, () => Adapters.All(_ => _.Error == null)));
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand CancelCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _cancelCommand ?? (_cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    // Cancel action
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### AdapterViewModel

The properties are self-explanatory. I also implemented `IDataErrorInfo` to tell WPF how to validate your inputs. (There are probably frameworks to make this easier... I've used `CSLA` but that's overkill for this.)

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;

namespace NicApp
{
    public class AdapterViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _ipAddress;
        private string _subnet;
        private bool _useDhcp;
        private bool _useDns;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string IPAddress
        {
            get { return _ipAddress; }
            set
            {
                _ipAddress = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Subnet
        {
            get { return _subnet; }
            set
            {
                _subnet = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool UseDhcp
        {
            get { return _useDhcp; }
            set
            {
                _useDhcp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool UseDns
        {
            get { return _useDns; }
            set
            {
                _useDns = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return this[nameof(IPAddress)] ?? this[nameof(Subnet)];
            }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                IPAddress addr;

                if (columnName == nameof(IPAddress) && !UseDhcp && !System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(IPAddress, out addr))
                    return "Invalid IP Address";
                if (columnName == nameof(Subnet) && !UseDhcp && !System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(Subnet, out addr))
                    return "Invalid Subnet Mask";

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The result

[image: screenshot]

I'm sleepy and didn't want to leave you hanging, so I just threw this code up here. Sorry of my explanation was less than stellar. Hopefully this is enough to give you an idea of a route you could take to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it is going to do the trick. This explanation took you some time, and I appreciate it. I need to look closely at your example and absorb it. I have now started to refactor into MVVM, but I don't think I will have it done by then end of the evening. I am very grateful that you have set me on a path that I can start to understand the pattern and will mark the question as answered, as soon as I prove it to myself.